# How can I suppress message "... cannot be used as function"?

Tags: differential-equations

I'd really appreciate your help. The code gives me a solution, but in the end it says it cannot be used as function, which is not true.

Script:

```
SolveLDE[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}] := (
ClearAll[C1, C2, a, b, c, d];
x[t_] = C1 Exp[-2 t] + C2 Exp[4 t];
y[t_] = -3 C1 Exp[-2 t] + C2 Exp[4 t];
Example1 = Solve[x[x0] == x1 && y[y0] == y1, {C1, C2}];
C1 = C1 /. Example1[[1, 1]];
C2 = C2 /. Example1[[1, 2]];
\[Lambda] = {-2, 4};
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
X = {x[x0], y[x0]};
dX = {x'[x0], y'[x0]};
EquSys = 
 Solve[dX == A.X && 
     y[y0] == 1/b (x'[x0] - a x[x0]) && #^2 - Tr[A] # + Det[A] == 
      0 & /@ \[Lambda], {a, b, c, d}];
{{a, b, c, d}} = {a, b, c, d} /. EquSys;
res = DSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] + b y[t], y'[t] == c x[t] + d y[t], 
   x[x0] == x1, y[y0] == y1}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
)
SolveLDE[{0, 0}, {0, 1}]
```

As solution i get...

```
DSolve::dsfun: -(1/4) E^(-2 t)+E^(4 t)/4 cannot be used as a function. >>
DSolve[{E^(-2 t)/2 + E^(4 t) == 
 5/2 (-(1/4) E^(-2 t) + E^(4 t)/4) + 
 3/2 ((3 E^(-2 t))/4 + E^(4 t)/4), -(3/2) E^(-2 t) + E^(4 t) == 
 1/2 (-(3/4) E^(-2 t) - E^(4 t)/4) + 
 9/2 (-(1/4) E^(-2 t) + E^(4 t)/4), True, 
True}, {-(1/4) E^(-2 t) + E^(4 t)/4, (3 E^(-2 t))/4 + E^(4 t)/4}, t]
```

As you can see - the solution is in the bracket....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made definition for `x[t_]` and `y[t_]` and then supplied to `DSolve` as unknown functions.

A nasty correction is this

```
SolveLDE[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}] := (ClearAll[C1, C2, a, b, c, d];
  x[t_] = C1 Exp[-2 t] + C2 Exp[4 t];
  y[t_] = -3 C1 Exp[-2 t] + C2 Exp[4 t];
  Example1 = Solve[x[x0] == x1 && y[y0] == y1, {C1, C2}];
  C1 = C1 /. Example1[[1, 1]];
  C2 = C2 /. Example1[[1, 2]];
  \[Lambda] = {-2, 4};
  A = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
  X = {x[x0], y[x0]};
  dX = {x'[x0], y'[x0]};
  EquSys = 
   Solve[dX == A.X && 
       y[y0] == 1/b (x'[x0] - a x[x0]) && #^2 - Tr[A] # + Det[A] == 
        0 & /@ \[Lambda], {a, b, c, d}];
  {{a, b, c, d}} = {a, b, c, d} /. EquSys;
  res = DSolve[{xx'[t] == a xx[t] + b yy[t], 
     yy'[t] == c xx[t] + d yy[t], xx[x0] == x1, yy[y0] == y1}, {xx[t],
      yy[t]}, t])
SolveLDE[{0, 0}, {0, 1}]
```

I don't have time now to dig into the code and see how it can be simplified, however you should really split that into more reasonable bricks and use local variables/constants (`Module`/`With`).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may give you a better idea of how to use Mathematica for something like this:

```
SolveLDE[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}] := 
 Module[{x, y, a, b, c, d, C1, C2, Example1, \[Lambda], A, X, dX, 
   EquSys, res},

  x[t_] := C1 Exp[-2 t] + C2 Exp[4 t];
  y[t_] := -3 C1 Exp[-2 t] + C2 Exp[4 t];
  Example1 = Solve[x[x0] == x1 && y[y0] == y1, {C1, C2}];
  C1 = C1 /. Example1[[1, 1]];
  C2 = C2 /. Example1[[1, 2]];
  \[Lambda] = {-2, 4};
  A = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
  X = {x[x0], y[x0]};
  dX = {x'[x0], y'[x0]};
  EquSys = 
   Solve[dX == A.X && 
       y[y0] == 1/b (x'[x0] - a x[x0]) && #^2 - Tr[A] # + Det[A] == 
        0 & /@ \[Lambda], {a, b, c, d}];
  {{a, b, c, d}} = {a, b, c, d} /. EquSys;

  res = DSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] + b y[t], y'[t] == c x[t] + d y[t], 
     x[x0] == x1, y[y0] == y1}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
  ]

SolveLDE[{0, 0}, {0, 1}]

DSolve[{E^(-2 t)/2 + E^(4 t) == 
   5/2 (-(1/4) E^(-2 t) + E^(4 t)/4) + 
    3/2 ((3 E^(-2 t))/4 + E^(4 t)/4), -(3/2) E^(-2 t) + E^(4 t) == 
   1/2 (-(3/4) E^(-2 t) - E^(4 t)/4) + 
    9/2 (-(1/4) E^(-2 t) + E^(4 t)/4), True, 
  True}, {-(1/4) E^(-2 t) + E^(4 t)/4, (3 E^(-2 t))/4 + E^(4 t)/4}, t]
```

Not a complete answer but perhaps this moves you in the right direction.

Study `Module`, and how to write and form functions.

Looking more closely,, when you set:

```
Example1 = Solve[x[x0] == x1 && y[y0] == y1, {C1, C2}];
```

what do you intend x0 and y0 to represent?

You use them again in the lines:

```
dX = {x'[x0], y'[x0]};
EquSys = Solve[dX == A.X && y[y0] == 1/b (x'[x0] - a x[x0]) && #^2 - Tr[A] # + Det[A] == 0 & /@ \[Lambda], {a, b, c, d}];
```

and

```
res = DSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] + b y[t], y'[t] == c x[t] + d y[t], x[x0] == x1, y[y0] == y1}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

Without getting much deeper into this than I can right now, that could cause your problems.

Update your post or make a comment to clarify.

Comment: This doesn't work. As pointed out above, the problem is the definition of `x[t_]` `y[t_]` and their use inside `DSolve`.

Comment: I took Federico's advice into account and it worked.

Comment: @Federico -- No claim it works, just trying to sort through some of the confusion.

Comment: @Gasper -- Great, vote him up.  He deserves it, but do consider better structuring your code.  IT will vastly simplify your life ;-)

Comment: The meaning of x0,y0... What would like to achieve is to quickly get a solution for the calculations above for the already prescribed values of functions. Like for example x(0)=0 and y(0)=1. I'd like to change this values, and this is why i put "SolveLDE[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}] := " in the first line

Comment: @Gasper -- That actually was the clear part. It's all the rest that is messy. I suggest you follow Jagra's advice and take a peek at [Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html)